# (Ordered) Set Partitions in fixed-size Blocks

Tags: language-agnostic, math, recursion, combinatorics

Here is a function I would like to write but am unable to do so. Even if you
don't / can't give a solution I would be grateful for tips. For example,
I know that there is a correlation between the ordered represantions of the
sum of an integer and ordered set partitions but that alone does not help me in
finding the solution. So here is the description of the function I need:

### The Task

Create an efficient* function

```
List<int[]> createOrderedPartitions(int n_1, int n_2,..., int n_k)
```

that returns a list of arrays of all set partions of the set 
`{0,...,n_1+n_2+...+n_k-1}` in `number of arguments` blocks of size (in this 
order) `n_1,n_2,...,n_k` (e.g. `n_1=2, n_2=1, n_3=1 -> ({0,1},{3},{2}),...`).

Here is a usage example:

```
int[] partition = createOrderedPartitions(2,1,1).get(0);
partition[0]; // -> 0
partition[1]; // -> 1
partition[2]; // -> 3
partition[3]; // -> 2
```

Note that the number of elements in the list is
`(n_1+n_2+...+n_n choose n_1) * (n_2+n_3+...+n_n choose n_2) * ... *
(n_k choose n_k)`. Also, `createOrderedPartitions(1,1,1)` would create the 
permutations of `{0,1,2}` and thus there would be `3! = 6` elements in the
list.

* by efficient I mean that you should not initially create a bigger list
like all partitions and then filter out results. You should do it directly.

#### Extra Requirements

If an argument is 0 treat it as if it was not there, e.g.
`createOrderedPartitions(2,0,1,1)` should yield the same result as
`createOrderedPartitions(2,1,1)`. But at least one argument must not be 0.
Of course all arguments must be >= 0.

#### Remarks

The provided pseudo code is quasi Java but the language of the solution 
doesn't matter. In fact, as long as the solution is fairly general and can 
be reproduced in other languages it is ideal.

Actually, even better would be a return type of `List<Tuple<Set>>` (e.g. when
creating such a function in Python). However, then the arguments wich have
a value of 0 must not be ignored. `createOrderedPartitions(2,0,2)` would then
create

```
[({0,1},{},{2,3}),({0,2},{},{1,3}),({0,3},{},{1,2}),({1,2},{},{0,3}),...]
```

### Background

I need this function to make my mastermind-variation bot more efficient and
most of all the code more "beautiful". Take a look at the `filterCandidates`
function in [my source code](https://github.com/eugenkiss/Mastermind/blob/fc25378f7692d91eaa6c40d1ebce2493c4be59cc/strategies/eugen.lua#L65). There are unnecessary
/ duplicate queries because I'm simply using permutations instead of
specifically ordered partitions. Also, I'm just interested in how to write
this function.

### My ideas for (ugly) "solutions"

Create the powerset of `{0,...,n_1+...+n_k}`, filter out the subsets of size 
`n_1, n_2` etc. and create the  cartesian product of the n subsets. However 
this won't actually work because there would be duplicates, e.g. 
`({1,2},{1})...`

First choose `n_1` of `x = {0,...,n_1+n_2+...+n_n-1}` and put them in the
first set. Then choose `n_2` of `x without the n_1 chosen elements
beforehand` and so on. You then get for example `({0,2},{},{1,3},{4})`. Of
course, every possible combination must be created so `({0,4},{},{1,3},{2})`,
too, and so on. Seems rather hard to implement but might be possible.

### Research

I guess [this](http://www.codecogs.com/code/maths/discrete/combinatorics/permutations/partition.php) 
goes in the direction I want however I don't see how I can utilize it for my
specific scenario.

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations

Comment: Is this maybe more of a question for math.stackexchange.com since at root this is an algorithmic problem? Or perhaps even cstheory.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, it often helps to phrase your thoughts in order to come up with a solution. It seems that then the subconscious just starts working on the task and notifies you when it found the solution. So here is the solution to my problem in Python:

```
from itertools import combinations

def partitions(*args):
    def helper(s, *args):
        if not args: return [[]]
        res = []
        for c in combinations(s, args[0]):
            s0 = [x for x in s if x not in c]
            for r in helper(s0, *args[1:]):
                res.append([c] + r)
        return res
    s = range(sum(args))
    return helper(s, *args)

print partitions(2, 0, 2)
```

The output is:

```
[[(0, 1), (), (2, 3)], [(0, 2), (), (1, 3)], [(0, 3), (), (1, 2)], [(1, 2), (), (0, 3)], [(1, 3), (), (0, 2)], [(2, 3), (), (0, 1)]]
```

It is adequate for translating the algorithm to Lua/Java. It is basically the second idea I had.

### The Algorithm

As I already mentionend in the question the basic idea is as follows:

First choose `n_1` elements of the set `s := {0,...,n_1+n_2+...+n_n-1}` and put them in the
first set of the first tuple in the resulting list (e.g. `[({0,1,2},...` if the chosen elements are `0,1,2`). Then choose `n_2` elements of the set `s_0 := s without the n_1 chosen elements beforehand` and so on. One such a tuple might be `({0,2},{},{1,3},{4})`. Of
course, every possible combination is created so `({0,4},{},{1,3},{2})` is another such tuple and so on.

#### The Realization

At first the set to work with is created (`s = range(sum(args))`). Then this set and the arguments are passed to the recursive helper function `helper`.

`helper` does one of the following things: If all the arguments are processed return "some kind of empty value" to stop the recursion. Otherwise iterate through all the combinations of the passed set `s` of the length `args[0]` (the first argument after `s` in `helper`). In each iteration create the set `s0 := s without the elements in c` (the elements in `c` are the chosen elements from `s`), which is then used for the recursive call of `helper`.

So what happens with the arguments in `helper` is that they are processed one by one. `helper` may first start with `helper([0,1,2,3], 2, 1, 1)` and in the next invocation it is for example `helper([2,3], 1, 1)` and then `helper([3], 1)` and lastly `helper([])`. Of course another "tree-path" would be `helper([0,1,2,3], 2, 1, 1)`, `helper([1,2], 1, 1)`, `helper([2], 1)`, `helper([])`. All these "tree-paths" are created and thus the required solution is generated.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need this function at all, since there is a far simpler way to filter out possibilities in mastermind. Nonetheless it was interesting to write this algorithm.